# Transposing Matrices - Horizontal to Vertical - OpenGL ES - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, opengl-es, 3d

Say I have the following matrix which is vertical :

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
```

And I want to translate this so that it is ordered horizontally - i.e :

```
{0,4,8,12,1,5,9,13,2,6,10,14,3,7,11,15}
```

What would be easiest way to achieve this ?

EDIT

I have already done this by manually mapping each item to the correct position, but wanted to see if there was a better way out of curiosity.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for every *0 <= j < i < n* (when *n^2* is the size of the matrix), you should swap the `[i][j]` and `[j][i]` elements.

```
int mat[4][4]={{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15}};
int i,j,temp;
for (i=0;i<4;i++)
 for (j=0;j<i;j++) {
  temp=mat[i][j];
  mat[i][j]=mat[j][i];
  mat[j][i]=temp;
 }
```